# How to join promise to a promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have `func1` function which returns a promise. In `func2` i have started promise chain.
What i want to do here is, i want to use `func1` resolve message in old promise chain, and i want this code to be less complex. What is the best way to join `func1` promise to promise chain in `func2`

```
var func1 = function(){
  return new promise(function(resolve, reject){
    //some operations here
  });
};

var func2 = function(){
  promise.resolve(someFuncSync())
    .then(function(){
    //this is the old promise chain

        func1()
          .then(function(message,error){
             return message;
             //i want use this return value in old promise chain
          });

         console.log(message);
        //printing  func1 returned message in old promise chain
    })
};
```

Comment: you can't do this. You have access to message only inside `then` func1.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski You should post it as answer. Just use `then(function(message) { console.log(message) })`.

Comment: What do you mean by "chain"? A sequence? And what do you want to do with the resolve values of func1 and func2, respectively?

Comment: @Grundy That is incorrect. You can return a promise or return a value to pass it down the promise chain.

Comment: @doug65536, so you can provide sample without using `then`?

Comment: @Grundy Sample of what? Passing it down the promise chain? https://jsfiddle.net/zdt68bfx/

Comment: @doug65536, so you anything use `then` instead return value

Comment: @Grundy and [an example of passing multiple independent values down the chain](https://jsfiddle.net/zdt68bfx/1/). Any of those items passed to `Promise.all` could itself be a promise, whose resolved value would get to next `.then`.

Comment: example of [multi-value pass-down-the-chain with one of them async](https://jsfiddle.net/zdt68bfx/2/)

Comment: @doug65536, but anyway `then` :)

Answer (score 2):

Just return the new promise from within a `.then()` handler and it will automatically be added to the previous chain and will then control the resolved value of the old promise chain.

The outer promise won't resolve until the newly returned promise is resolved and the inner promise will control the final resolved value.  I added the `return` statement here in front of your call to `return func1()` to add it to the chain:

```
var func2 = function(){
  promise.resolve(someFuncSync())
    .then(function(){
    //this is the old promise chain

        // ADDED return here
        return func1()
          .then(function(message,error){
             return message;
             //i want use this return value in old promise chain
          });
    })
};
```

---

There are several other things I'd change in your code because it looks like everything you have above can be distilled down to just this:

```
var func2 = function () {
    someFuncSync();
    return func1();
};
```

This allows you do then do:

```
func2().then(function(message) {
    // process message here
}, function(err) {
    // process err here
});
```

Summary of changes:

1. There's no need to wrap `someFuncSync()` into promise if it's always synchronous.  You can just call it and then start your promise chain.
2. Since standard promises only return a single value (not something like `(message, error)`, there's really no reason for the callback with `return message` in it.  You can just return the promise directly.
3. Added `return` in front of `func1()` so we are returning the promise.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The `return` would only be a possible ASI problem if there were no more text after `return` on that line.

Comment: Personally, I always put the first `.then()` on the same line as the previous function call since I think that read more clearly that there's more to come - this particular scheme was what the OP was using here.

Comment: @Srinesh - Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Man, some of these answers are really overthinking things.  The beauty of promises is their simplicity:

```
return func1().then(func2)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `.then` callback may return a promise and it'll be added automatically to the chain:

```
// createURL() returns a promise that returns a URL.
createURL(...).then(url => {
  return fetch(url)
})
.then(response => {
  // :-)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do it by adding an extra step to the old promise chain.

This assumes you don't need to use the value resolved from the old promise chain in the new.

```
var func1 = function(){
  return new promise(function(resolve, reject){
    //some operations here
  });
};

var func2 = function(){
  promise.resolve(someFuncSync())
    .then(function(arg){

        return promise.all([
            arg, // Argument that original promise resolved with
            func1() // The new extra promise
        ])
    })
    .spread(function(arg, message){
        // Now i have the new message and also the return value from the old promise.
         console.log(message);
        //printing  func1 returned message in old promise chain
    })
};
```